# Write .csv file with list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]
```

I need to take this list and make a .csv file, so the output needs to be like this:

[image]

I have this piece of code but it's giving me errors so I don't really know what to do at this point.

```
import csv
file = [{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]

keys = file[0].keys()
with open('output.csv','wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file,keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(file)
```

Comment: Be more specific than *"errors"*, give a [mcve].

Comment: It gives me a ValueError : dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Ana'

Comment: The error is in the line `dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file,keys)`. The variable `keys` is false. It's better by using of  `[('Eva', 5), ('Ana', 53), ('Ada', 12)]` instead of `[{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]`.

Comment: I need it to be with a list of dictionaries so I can't do it with [ ('Eva' ,5.... )],etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be like this;

```
import csv

fieldnames = ["Owner's Names", "Average Age"]
file = [{'Eva': 5}, {'Ana': 53}, {'Ada': 12}]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for f in file:
        writer.writerow({fieldnames[0]: f.keys()[0], fieldnames[1]: f.values()[0]})
```

I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: This was very helpful and now the function is working as it should. Thank you :)